# How best to deal with None values in a dictionary when combining values?

Tags: python

I'm trying to amend a key's value in a dictionary which should be set as the addition of two other key's values if the key value is None or key doesn't exist.
However I get an error when trying to add None's  `'unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`

how can I best write this to deal with missing keys or keys which exist but have None as the value? 
the code I'm trying is:

```
    for quote in quotes_results:
        exit_fee_combined = quote.get('exitFeeA', None) + quote.get('exitFeeB', None)
        quote.setdefault('exitFeeCombined', exit_fee_combined)
```

this horrible bit of code below does the job but seems overly complex (I couldn't use setdefault as it will not use the default if it finds the key but with `None` as the value).
Any way to improve it?

```
    for quote in quotes_results:
        exit_fee_A = quote.get('exitFeeA', None)
        exit_fee_B = quote.get('exitFeeB', None)
        if exit_fee_A and exit_fee_B:
            exit_fee_combined = exit_fee_B + exit_fee_A
        elif exit_fee_A or exit_fee_B:
            exit_fee_combined = exit_fee_A or exit_fee_B
        else:
            exit_fee_combined = None
        existing_combined_fee = quote.get('exitFeeCombined', None)
        if not existing_combined_fee:
            quote['exitFeeCombined'] = exit_fee_combined
```

Comment: Can't exit fees be `0` as a default instead of `None` ? Then it's `(quote.get('exitFeeA', 0) + quote.get('exitFeeB', 0)) or None` ?

Comment: Sorry no I should have mentioned that, the output goes to a template where ultimately the `None` is displayed , ie coerced to `'None'`.  Actually I don't think your suggestiong will work anyway if `quote['exitFeeA'] = None` already, I'll get the original error for trying to use `+` with `None`

Comment: Okay... but you're passing through None anyway and the above will do the same... not quite seeing what the difference is?

Comment: Right... well, if your exit fees aren't fees and are all over the place, then you've probably got a fair bit of defensive code to cater for it... So maybe what you've got is the best you can do - pending you telling us what is/isn't valid at what point and when...

Comment: Having said that `(quote.get('A') or 0) + (quote.get('B') or 0)` will cover your example there

Comment: The input might have the keys present with a value or with None's or not be present at all (less likely but possible), the output should be None or an addition of the values if present. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Which `((quote.get('A') or 0) + (quote.get('B') or 0) or None)` will do

Comment: You are right that works thank you! If you put it as an answer I'll accept, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Jon's comment,  this is the best solution:

```
((quote.get('A') or 0) + (quote.get('B') or 0) or None)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for quote in quotes_results:
    exit_fee_combined = quote.get('exitFeeA', 0) + quote.get('exitFeeB', 0)
```

In this instance, the simplest solution is to choose the result of `get` correctly.  Since adding 0 has no effect for numbers, then just do that.  If your value is a string, use `""` instead of `0`.

Comment: Your answer sounds a lot like [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46475421/how-best-to-deal-with-none-values-in-a-dictionary-when-combining-values#comment79905874_46475421)?

Comment: Perhaps.  I was writing an answer while someone was writing a comment.  Didn't see the comment until I had posted my answer.